# How can two identical nodelets in one process remap topics and services?

Tags: ros, remapping, camera-drivers, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to run a stereo pair of 1394 cameras as nodelets. It would be
good to run both in the same address space with stereo_image_proc.
But, I can't figure out how to remap the topic and service names to do
that.

With nodes, I can get the right topic and service names like this:

```
<launch>
 <group ns="stereo" >

   <!-- left camera -->
   <node pkg="camera1394" type="camera1394_node" name="left_node" >
     <rosparam file="$(find camera1394)/tests/left.yaml" />
     <remap from="camera" to="left" />
   </node>

   <!-- right camera -->
   <node pkg="camera1394" type="camera1394_node" name="right_node" >
     <rosparam file="$(find camera1394)/tests/right.yaml" />
     <remap from="camera" to="right" />
   </node>

 </group>
</launch>
```

The equivalent nodelet launch script does not work:

```
<launch>
 <group ns="stereo" >

   <!-- nodelet manager process -->
   <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="camera_nodelet_manager"
         args="manager" />

   <!-- left camera -->
   <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="left_camera"
         args="load camera1394/driver camera_nodelet_manager" >
     <rosparam file="$(find camera1394)/tests/left.yaml" />
     <remap from="camera" to="left" />
   </node>

   <!-- right camera -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="right_camera"
        args="load camera1394/driver camera_nodelet_manager" >
     <rosparam file="$(find camera1394)/tests/right.yaml" />
     <remap from="camera" to="right" />
  </node>

 </group>
</launch>
```

The failure is that neither `<remap>` works and both nodelets try to
declare the same service names: `/stereo/camera/set_camera_info`,
`/stereo/camera/image_raw/compressed/set_parameters`, etc..

It seems that the `<remap>` has to be applied to the nodelet manager
node, not the nodes doing the load.

So, how do I remap camera-->left for one nodelet and camera-->right
for the other?

Or, is there some other way to solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9071/how-can-two-identical-nodelets-in-one-process-remap-topics-and-services?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nodelets are supposed to work exactly as nodes do.  This looks like a bug in the interaction between roscpp and nodelets.  I've filed a ticket: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4794

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-02-16**:
I agree that it **should** work that way. I had not noticed that it does work when not using subordinate names. Let's discuss what to do using ticket #4794.

**Comment by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on 2014-03-28**:
have been this bug solved?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-03-28**:
It was fixed 3 years ago in ROS Diamondback.